# Restkit Post always goes in the failure part

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, post, restkit

I have a restkit function where I call a webservice for checking my login credentials. In this call I give my e-mail and password as parameters. Here you can see the code.

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://****.com/nl/webservice/"]];


NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:_txtLogin.text,@"email",_txtPass.text,@"pwd", nil];
      NSLog(@"till here");
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"company-user/login/apikey/key*****?" parameters:dictionary];
      NSLog(@"till here2");
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [manager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    NSLog(@"till here3");
    NSLog(@"Loading mapping result: %@", result);
}failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    //Failure
    NSLog(@"error is:%@ ",error);
    NSLog(@"FAILUREE!");
}];

      NSLog(@"till here4");
[operation start];
      NSLog(@"till here5");
```

But for some reason I goes to the failure part. It first gives me a status 200 back, but then an error. You can see my log over here.

```
2013-01-07 20:33:45.858 Offitel2[26195:c07] till here
2013-01-07 20:33:45.859 Offitel2[26195:c07] till here2
2013-01-07 20:33:45.860 Offitel2[26195:c07] till here4
2013-01-07 20:33:47.252 Offitel2[26195:c07] till here5
2013-01-07 20:33:47.254 Offitel2[26195:c07] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:152 POST 'http://virtuele-receptie.preview.sanmax.be/nl/webservice/company-user/login/apikey/key12345678?'
2013-01-07 20:33:47.255 Offitel2[26195:c07] I restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:179 POST 'http://virtuele-receptie.preview.sanmax.be/nl/webservice/company-user/login/apikey/key12345678?' (200 OK) [0.0005 s]
2013-01-07 20:33:47.255 Offitel2[26195:c07] error is:Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded." UserInfo=0xa869130 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://virtuele-receptie.preview.sanmax.be/nl/webservice/company-user/login/apikey/key12345678?, NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the URL 'http://virtuele-receptie.preview.sanmax.be/nl/webservice/company-user/login/apikey/key12345678?', which failed to match all (0) response descriptors:, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded., keyPath=null, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://virtuele-receptie.preview.sanmax.be/nl/webservice/company-user/login/apikey/key12345678?, NSUnderlyingError=0xa8695b0 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched."} 
2013-01-07 20:33:47.256 Offitel2[26195:c07] FAILUREE!
```

Can anybody help me with this ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to perform an object mapping for a response to call to a webservice, you must provide response descriptors. Please take a look at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping for instructions and examples.

Comment: isn't it possible that I can read the json file only? without object mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

I was asking me the same thing, "**isn't it possible that I can read the json file only? without object mapping?** " and the solution that i found is that RestKit 0.20 uses AFNetworking. So, if you need to make requests without mapping do the next thing.

```
[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://****.com/nl/webservice/"]];
NSDictionary *params     = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            _txtLogin.text, @"email",
                            _txtPass.text,  @"pwd",
                            nil];
[httpClient postPath:@"company-user/login/apikey/key*****?" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSData *jsonData = [operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *jsonDict =    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonData
                                                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                  error: &error];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonDict);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```